# Use cpx and typescript to watch and serve file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc, npm-scripts

I am using [cpx](https://github.com/mysticatea/cpx) to copy `.yml` files and [typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) to compile `.ts` files. All of this is then served with an *npm script* using node as follows:

```
start: "tsc && cpx \"src/**/*.yml\" dist/src && node ./dist/server.js
```

This functions without a problem on the production server. The problem arises when I try to run the setup in watch mode during development using [tsc-watch](https://github.com/gilamran/tsc-watch) as follows:

```
"start:watch": "cpx \"src/**/*.yml\" dist/src --watch && tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/server.js\" --onFailure \"echo Beep! Boop! Compilation Failed!\""
```

I get the failure message *Beep! Boop! Compilation Failed!* when I run `npm run start:watch` which however changes to what I would expect when the compilation was successfully. The app then runs correctly.

Is it possible to use `tsc-watch` together with another script command in watch mode without getting this confusing behaviour?

Comment: Your npm script is not valid JSON. Either; **1.** Delete the double quotes from the path provided to `cpx`, i.e. change `"src/**/*.yml"` to `src/**/*.yml`. **2.** Or escape them, i.e. change `"src/**/*.yml"` to `\"src/**/*.yml\"`.

Comment: @RobC thanks for the correction. The escaping was somehow removed while pasting from my IDE.