# Automatically compile TypeScript sources and copy static (template)files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ejs, nodemon

While debugging an express server my 'build & run' process consists of 3 steps:

- Compiling TypeScript sources using `tsc`
- Copy static files like images and templates to `dist/`
- Run the compiled `server.js` file

Each of these steps can be automated using a *watch mode*, but I'm struggling to combine the three together.
I managed to get it working by using [tsc-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-watch) to watch the TypeScript sources, [cpx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx) to copy the static files and finally [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) to restart the server.
This approach *works* but there are a couple of issues:

- `cpx` only watches files that existed at the time it started (I think `tsc-watch` does this too *sometimes*, it's a little weird)
- This approach requires 3 commands in 3 seperate terminals, which is just plain inconvenient
- Both `cpx` & `tsc-watch` do not handle `Ctrl+C` exit correctly, causing all sorts of issues

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191248/how-to-add-a-post-tsc-build-task-that-copy-files/44283813) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276862/is-there-a-way-to-use-npm-scripts-to-run-tsc-watch-nodemon-watch) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338054/nodemon-not-refreshing-when-using-typescript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158954/use-cpx-and-typescript-to-watch-and-serve-file-changes) that relate to this subject, but none of them fix the aforementioned issues (although they did tell me about cpx & tsc-watch).
I don't want to use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) because it can cause timing issues and it mixes console output from the different processes (most notably `tsc-watch` and the actual server).

Using `tsc-watch`'es `--onSuccess` to copy the static files is not sufficient, since changes in the template files won't be picked up on. This can be worked around by changing a comment in a source file, but this triggers a complete recompile (restarting the server).
Using [webpack's watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) wouldn't be sufficient either since it doesn't pick up on new files and contaminates the console output even more.

Are there any solutions to this that I may have missed? Should I just write a script that automatically opens the 3 required terminals?

Comment: I may not be able to help you reach your end goal, but I have been using [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) which uses `ts-node` under the hood. I believe you can add your `onSuccess` to your `tsconfig.json`. `ts-node-dev` will watch and restart your server when you make changes to `.ts` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) with the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).

Although the watch mode is unfortunately [broken](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/347) at the time of writing, it seems like it fits my needs *almost* perfectly:

- This approach requires only 2 terminals (one for webpack, the other for nodemon). It's not perfect, but it's a lot better than 3.
- New files *should* be picked up automatically (although currently not working 100% correctly)
- A change in static files *shouldn't* cause a complete recompile that would cause the server to restart (again this currently doesn't work 100% correctly)
- Webpack handles `Ctrl+C` exits gracefully
- And the most important reason for me: [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) allows me to specify how I want my files to be copied in more detailed with the [context](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#context) option

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing a similar dilemma, I would recommend using [SWC](https://swc.rs/docs/getting-started)

You should be able to achieve what you want with just this line

```
swc src -D -d dist --strip-leading-paths -w
```

Use the -w flag to watch for file changes

Then you can use nodemon for watching for file changes on your dist directory